# Limit number of Pages?

Tags: php, pagination

I use the following code to limit the links of different pages up to 10 pages per page.

```
$start = ( floor($page/10) * 10 ) + 1;
for( $i = $start; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    if( $i >= ($start + 10)){
        break;
    }
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i  .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

But it shows next 10 pages. I want it to work in reverse order also such that to show previous 10 page too.
help?

Comment: Surely `(floor($page/10) * 10) +1` is the same as `$start = $page+1`

Comment: If you want to go in reverse order then change the for loop to go `$i--` and of course change the terminating condition.

Comment: `for($i = $start; $i < $start + 10; $i++)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$start = ( floor($page/10) * 10 ) + 1;
$start = ($start > 10) ? ($start-10) : 1;
for( $i = $start; $i < $totalPages; $i++){
    if( $i >= ($start + 10)){
        break;
    }
    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page= '. $i  .'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">' . $i . '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```